# High performance mysql INSERTs

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, mysql-connector, mariadb

I'm currently rewriting an old ASP \ ASP.NET application. Since I cannot do a full rewrite I need to go by parts. 
Right now I'm upgrading the code base from ODBC to .net connector.

There's a function that makes a insert (or 2) each time a user visits a page. Performance is very important. Here is the old ODBC function that INSERTs data:

```
public string WriteDb(string sql)
{
    myConnection.Close();
    myConnection.Open();    
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
    return myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
}
```

Here is the one I'm working on:

```
void WriteDb(string sql, ICollection<MySqlParameter> pms)
{
    using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(sConnection))
    {
        using(MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            foreach (var p in pms)
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(mySqlParameter);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm worried about connection pool exhaustion. Could my function be improved?

Comment: why are you doing 2 inserts each time a user visits a page...can't you make a cache on the server and do the insert every x minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note 1 - The Query**
I think, one of the biggest changes is the you now insert something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (KEY, KEY) VALUES (VALUE, VALUE);
INSERT INTO tablename (KEY, KEY) VALUES (VALUE, VALUE);
```

But a better insert will be:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (KEY, KEY) VALUES (VALUE, VALUE), (VALUE, VALUE);
```

Which does not need 2 queries and communication to the database, but just 1. 
I don't know if you have a query like this. But it would improve the performance.

**Note 2 - The connection**
You do a new MySqlConnection for each query you have. Making a connection is a heavy method. Cache your connection untill you stop using it and close it when your done, this will help a lot! Maybe even better to use the same connection for all the MySQL functions you execute on the page. And close it at the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This is used in a counter style script that sits in a different server, so only this page get requested in that particular server. Meaning, I should probably also cache the queries locally and then do a bulk insert or something (?)

Comment: I think starting the connection is the most heavy execution if you have a simple insert query. I would start with caching the connection for 5 minutes or something but don´t forget to close it. Otherwise you will have a maxconnections limit reached at your mysql server.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I should cache the connection handle  keep it open for 5 minutes, and after that close it? Then on the next request, create a new connection, cache it for 5 mins, etc. Or should I close it immediately after use, even though it's cached?